# Why my confirmation message did not fire from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have the following code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strScript = "if(confirm('Do you confirm?')){alert('OK'); }else{alert('cancel')}";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Confirmation", strScript, true);

}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strScript = "if(confirm('Do you confirm?')){return false; }else{return true;}";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Confirmation", strScript, true);

}
```

Button1 is displaying the confirmation message and then based on my selection respective alert message is appearing.

However when I click Button2 I do not even get the confirmation message.

Comment: This might sound trivial, but can you confirm both events are rigged up correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the code is wrong - you can't have `return` outside of a function, it's bad syntax.

You have to attach such code to *something*, for example to button click event:

```
Button2.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you confirm?');";
```

Have such code in the `Page_Load` event (or directly in the `.aspx`) and then clicking the button will trigger confirmation dialog that if cancelled, will cancel the button click.